# Do Mandarin people use 補鑊 as slang to represent fence-mending or damage control?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

Cantonese people often use 補鑊 to mean fence-mending or damage control.

Do Mandarin people use this phrase as well? If not, what phrase would be the Mandarin equivalent?

Comment: The literal equivalent would be 补锅, but that certainly doesn't carry the same connotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [補鑊](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/38233/)
>
> fence-mending; damage control; get a problem fixed
>
> This term is used in Cantonese, not Mandarin/Standard written Chinese

[補救](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/4250/) (remedy) can be used in both Mandarin and Cantonese

Example:

事發後才去**補救**已經太遅了 (Mandarin)

事發後先至去**補救**已經太遅啦 (Cantonese)

事發後先至去**補鑊**已經太遅啦 (Cantonese)

~

現在**補救**還來得及 (Mandarin)

而家**補救**仲趕得切 (Cantonese)

而家**補鑊**仲趕得切 (Cantonese)

*補鑊 and 補救 are mostly interchangeable in Cantonese*